# Automatically align 104 subplot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

Using `Matlab2tikz` I generated a file containing 104 subplots aligned in a very specific manner. I then inserted `\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right},}`, compiled and obtained the final PDF which was fine, except the subplots arrangement is still not satisfactory:

[image]

I am trying to organize better the subplots such that:

1. there will be the same vertically spacing,
2. Only two `ylabels` per subplot

Is there a possibility to do this, without having to modify every single `addplot`?

**Update:** 
Using the solution proposed from [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295152/95441), I noticed that the order is still wrong. This is because the generated *.tikz file started from the second subplot (from the left) in the bottom row and positioned following subplots relative to it. This of course made the resulting figure using [`groupplot`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf#page=427) completely wrong. Hence, I think i am obliged to stick to the [`axis`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf#page=40) environment, and play on the `yticklabels` to improve the spacing.

Any idea how to automatically fix three `yticklabels` per subplot?

Answer (score 3):

1. I think the easiest (consistent) way to implement this is using the `groupplots` library (have a look at [section 5.8 of the PGFPlots manual on page 428ff (in v1.13)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=428).
2. Since you haven't specified exactly *what* "two ylabels" you need, I suggest playing a bit with the keys `max space between ticks` and `try min ticks`. Other keys of interest could be `ytick` (in combination with `ytick distance`) or `yticklabels from table`. All of these keys could be given as optional arguments to the `\nextgroupplot` command directly or - in case they should be repeated themselves - as styles which you can define in the preamble.

Please find a really simple example for the `groupplot` environment below.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            tiny,
            /tikz/mark size=1.5pt,
            group style={
                group name=my plots,
                group size=2 by 2,
                horizontal sep=4mm,      % <-- default: 1cm
                vertical sep=2mm,        % <-- default: 1cm
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
            },
            width=3cm,
            height=3cm,
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[group/empty plot]
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};
        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot coordinates{(0,0) (1,2) (2,1)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: But with this, I have to add 104 `groupplot`manually! Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @user2536125, no, you only need/have _one_ `groupplot` environment, but you have to place 104 `\nextgroupplot` commands.  And I cannot suggest another solution when you don't state more details on where the plots in your above picture are coming from, if there are patterns of plots for the alignment and stuff like that.  In short, when you are more precise on what you have and what you need, there maybe a chance for a "better" solution ;)

Comment: This worked and improved the spacing. However, it changed the order of subplots. I just asked in a seperate  [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301627/force-groupplot-to-start-from-the-bottom-left-corner) about this issue. Maybe you can provide a solution?